# pull a database from genymotion emulator on to local disk

Tags: android, sqlite, adb, genymotion

I am using genymotion for my dev and when I create a database I can't see it in DDMS folder of genymotion emulator.

When searched on google I am able to see the database on adb shell but don't know how to pull the database to my local disk to view the data.

Can anyone please let me know the process.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can (also) pull the data from your device to your host by copying it to a shared folder:

```
adb shell su 0 cp /data/data/<package.name>/databases/<database.name> /mnt/shared/
```

[Here is](https://plus.google.com/111561249038747241670/posts/d2ogLdU1rZw) how to setup the shared folder:

> - Go to your VirtualBox VM setting / Shared folder tab
> - Add a shared folder with the folder you want to shared, and check the "auto mount" option
> - Start your VM as usual from the Genymotion software
> - Your shared folder is available in the /mnt/shared directory (multiple shared folders are supported)

Comment: Thanks eyal for your reply... your solution worked but a small change we need to remove `-c` and rest of all is fine.

Comment: I've edited the post, actually you need to put the id of the superuser (O) after the su word to make it work.

Comment: After a few tests, it seems that the su command is not the same depending on your Genymotion template version. So, sometimes you must use `adb shell su cp...`, `adb shell su -c cp...` or `adb shell su 0 cp...`

Comment: Np eyal... I will make a note of your suggestion and use it when needed.

Answer (score 10):

Try on Genymotion 2.3:

```
adb shell su -c cp /data/data/<package.name>/databases/<database.name> /sdcard/
```

and on other version :

```
adb shell su 0 cp /data/data/<package.name>/databases/<database.name> /sdcard/
```

And pull it from the device

```
adb pull /sdcard/<database.name>
```

(edited, not the same comportment of su in 2.3 and 4.3)

Comment: Thanks for your reply slvn instead of pull command I can directly go to the folder on my hard disk and can pick the file. I fell this is the much simpler way....

Comment: Depends if you like shared folder :)

Answer (score 0):

pull database using adb commands

```
 adb pull /data/data/com.android.packagename/databases.datebase.db
```

the db will be pulled to current location where terminal is pointing to

then open db using sqliteman